# Explain this reference to Luke Starkiller in The Flash

Tags: star-wars, dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, reference

In The Flash S3 Ep 14 - Attack on Central City, Cisco and Gypsy are talking. Gypsy is in a cell, and Cisco is trying to convince her to help the team. Gypsy says

> Are you trying to Luke Starkiller me?

I know that Starkiller was Luke's name  in original drafts of Star Wars, and the implication is that this is the character's name on Gypsy's Earth, but I don't get how the situation they are in is relevant to Star Wars and Luke Skywalker/Starkiller. What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm... I just watched that episode last night and completely missed the reference altogether.

Comment: The Jedi mind trick, perhaps?

Comment: My best guess is that she's referring to the way Luke was recruited, sort of against his will, to fight the evil Empire.

Comment: Closest parallel I can see if Luke (Cisco) trying to convince Han (Gypsy) to join in the attack on the Death Star.

Comment: I presumed since she is not from Earth 1, they call Luke Skywalker, Luke Starkiller. Implied she knew of Star Wars but because its a different universe the name was slightly different. And the reference was Cisco needed her help to defeat "The Empire" a la Grodd.

Comment: All these suggestions so far seem a bit of a stretch to me. None of them are very specific to Star Wars. But I still can't think of any specific scene this one mirrors or references.

Comment: It's probably just some throw away line that they used to be like "Hey, these worlds are so different, look at how different they are, hahaha, so different". Once again, writers underestimate the perceptiveness of their fanbase.

Comment: I've not seen the Flash episode, but from the context you've given, it sounds like it might be a reference to Luke guilt-tripping Han into helping the rebellion attack the Death Star, the whole "They could use a good pilot like you. You're turning your back on them." and "All right. Well, take care of yourself, Han. I guess that's what you're best at, isn't it?" scene.

Comment: @delinear. That's the best theory so far. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it in a day or two absent any better answers.

Comment: There are lots of parallelism jokes in the Flash between universes, not just this episode. Lots of times things are the same but with tiny detail variations. Earth 1's Luke Skywalker is Gypsy's Luke Starkiller. And yes Starkiller was the original first draft name for Luke but was changed later... at least on this earth :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I saw the episode I thought the meaning was, "Are you trying to Jedi mind trick me?" Based on the context from the episode it makes sense.  I have looked around and can not find anything from the Berlanti production team to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

I think Luke Starkiller played an Obi-Wan-like role in the original Star Wars. If that's the version that got made on Earth-19, maybe he says something like what Cisco said with the whole, "we need you" spiel.

> Since commencing his writing process in January 1973, Lucas had done "various rewrites in the evenings after the day's work." He would write four different screenplays for Star Wars, "searching for just the right ingredients, characters and storyline. It's always been what you might call a good idea in search of a story." By May 1974, he had expanded the film treatment into a rough draft screenplay, adding elements such as the Sith, the Death Star, and a general by the name of Annikin Starkiller. He changed Starkiller to an adolescent boy, and he shifted the general into a supporting role as a member of a family of dwarfs. Lucas envisioned the Corellian smuggler, Han Solo, as a large, green-skinned monster with gills. He based Chewbacca on his Alaskan Malamute dog, Indiana (whom he would later use as namesake for his character Indiana Jones), who often acted as the director's "co-pilot" by sitting in the passenger seat of his car.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film)#Writing)

Comment: I think that idea was put forward in the comments. I always thought the Luke Starkiller character was just Luke Skywalker with a different name though.

Comment: If you have a source to back this up, that would make for a better answer. As it stand, this is more suited as a comment. I recommend you take our [tour] to see what sort of answer we are looking for here. Welcome to the site!

Comment: "This script would be re-written for the fourth and final draft, dated January 1, 1976, as _The Adventures of Luke Starkiller as taken from the Journal of the Whills, Saga I: The Star Wars_." from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film))

Answer (score -2):

So my this is my take on it: right after she asks, he has a look of confusion and says “maybe I am,” implying to the audience that he doesn’t get the reference either and doesn’t know if he is or isn’t because he’s probably never seen earth 19’s version of Star Wars.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Even if you're correct and Cisco doesn't get it, it doesn't mean that it doesn't mean something to Gypsy.  So what is _that_.